# sinatraのTemplate内で使うhelperを作りたい

Tags: ruby, sinatra

イメージ

```
#helper
view_helper do
    hoge(fuga) do
        "#{fuga}です"
    end
end

#view
hoge('ボブ') # ボブです
```

このように使いたいのですが、どのような方法がよいのでしょうか?
そもそも作り方がわかりません。

おしえてください

Comment: sinatraのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 2):

Sinatra のFAQ に記述があるようです

[Sinatra: Frequently Asked Questions - How do I access helpers from within my views?](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#helpview)

> In hello.rb:
>
> ```
> helpers do
>   def em(text)
>     "<em>#{text}</em>"
>   end
> end
>
> get '/hello' do
>   @subject = 'World'
>   haml :hello
> end
> ```
>
> In views/hello.haml:
>
> ```
> %p= "Hello " + em(@subject)
> ```